# check if app is force closed in electron js?

Tags: javascript, electron

My question is How do I know if my app is closed from the task manager in windows or from system monitor in Ubuntu(Linux)?

I logout user profile from the app when they close the app but that happened only on close event. when I try to force quit app from task manager log out won't work

Comment: Did you try 'before-quit' event ? https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#%C3%A9v%C3%A9nement--before-quit

Comment: is it an option to have the user log in when opening? if you always want to log the user out when the app is closed (forced or regularly), requiring the user to log in every time could work.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible per the nodejs documentation on [signal events](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events) to have a listener for `SIGKILL`, however you can add one for `SIGTERM`. Here are the other signal events:

> 'SIGUSR1' is reserved by Node.js to start the debugger. It's possible to install a listener but doing so might interfere with the debugger.
>
> 'SIGTERM' and 'SIGINT' have default handlers on non-Windows platforms that reset the terminal mode before exiting with code 128 + signal number. If one of these signals has a listener installed, its default behavior will be removed (Node.js will no longer exit).
>
> 'SIGPIPE' is ignored by default. It can have a listener installed.
>
> 'SIGHUP' is generated on Windows when the console window is closed, and on other platforms under various similar conditions. See signal(7). It can have a listener installed, however Node.js will be unconditionally terminated by Windows about 10 seconds later. On non-Windows platforms, the default behavior of SIGHUP is to terminate Node.js, but once a listener has been installed its default behavior will be removed.
>
> 'SIGTERM' is not supported on Windows, it can be listened on.
>
> 'SIGINT' from the terminal is supported on all platforms, and can usually be generated with +C (though this may be configurable). It is not generated when terminal raw mode is enabled.
>
> 'SIGBREAK' is delivered on Windows when + is pressed, on non-Windows platforms it can be listened on, but there is no way to send or generate it.
>
> 'SIGWINCH' is delivered when the console has been resized. On Windows, this will only happen on write to the console when the cursor is being moved, or when a readable tty is used in raw mode.
>
> 'SIGKILL' cannot have a listener installed, it will unconditionally terminate Node.js on all platforms.
>
> 'SIGSTOP' cannot have a listener installed.
>
> 'SIGBUS', 'SIGFPE', 'SIGSEGV' and 'SIGILL', when not raised artificially using kill(2), inherently leave the process in a state from which it is not safe to attempt to call JS listeners. Doing so might lead to the process hanging in an endless loop, since listeners attached using process.on() are called asynchronously and therefore unable to correct the underlying problem.